# How can I combine many values into a few groups while adding their response value?

Tags: r

I hope the title isn't too confusing here. If so, please advise me on how to make it more clear & I will do so.

I have 24 data sets of 93 observations each. There are only two variables, a factor (size, a number) and it's response (percent, also a number). The factor value ranges from 0-2000. I would like to combine these 93 observations into three groups based on factor values (0-2, 2-50, and 50-2000) and see the total combined response value for each. I have tried using the `group_by` and `summarize` functions, but I am fairly new with r and am in over my head.

Here is an example of my data using the `dput` function

```
> dput(data2)
structure(list(run = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", ""), size = c("0.375", 
"0.412", "0.452", "0.496", "0.545", "0.598", "0.656", "0.721", 
"0.791", "0.868", "0.953", "1.047", "1.149", "1.261", "1.385", 
"1.520", "1.668", "1.832", "2.011", "2.207", "2.423", "2.660", 
"2.920", "3.205", "3.519", "3.863", "4.240", "4.655", "5.110", 
"5.610", "6.158", "6.760", "7.421", "8.147", "8.943", "9.817", 
"10.78", "11.83", "12.99", "14.26", "15.65", "17.18", "18.86", 
"20.70", "22.73", "24.95", "27.39", "30.07", "33.01", "36.24", 
"39.78", "43.67", "47.94", "52.62", "57.77", "63.41", "69.61", 
"76.42", "83.89", "92.09", "101.1", "111.0", "121.8", "133.7", 
"146.8", "161.2", "176.9", "194.2", "213.2", "234.1", "256.9", 
"282.1", "309.6", "339.9", "373.1", "409.6", "449.7", "493.6", 
"541.9", "594.9", "653.0", "716.8", "786.9", "863.9", "948.3", 
"1041", "1143", "1255", "1377", "1512", "1660", "1822", "2000"
), percentage = c("0.013", "0.023", "0.034", "0.049", "0.061", 
"0.072", "0.083", "0.093", "0.10", "0.11", "0.12", "0.12", "0.13", 
"0.14", "0.14", "0.15", "0.15", "0.16", "0.17", "0.17", "0.18", 
"0.19", "0.20", "0.21", "0.22", "0.24", "0.25", "0.26", "0.28", 
"0.30", "0.31", "0.33", "0.35", "0.37", "0.39", "0.42", "0.45", 
"0.47", "0.50", "0.53", "0.56", "0.58", "0.59", "0.59", "0.58", 
"0.55", "0.52", "0.49", "0.46", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.44", 
"0.42", "0.38", "0.35", "0.32", "0.31", "0.33", "0.36", "0.42", 
"0.49", "0.59", "0.74", "0.94", "1.19", "1.49", "1.82", "2.18", 
"2.55", "2.94", "3.34", "3.78", "4.25", "4.73", "5.20", "5.60", 
"5.87", "5.93", "5.77", "5.37", "4.77", "4.03", "3.21", "2.36", 
"1.55", "0.81", "0.30", "0.056", "0.0044", "0", "0", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-93L))
```

Thank you very much for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply want to subset some rows based on some conditions (at least for the 1st part of your question). Could you give an example of the output you are expecting so I can help you with your problem? Thank you.

You could use :

```
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(data)
data <- data[, size := as.numeric(size)]

group1 <- data[size <= 2,]
group2 <- data[size > 2 & size <= 50,]
group3 <- data[size > 50 & size <= 2000,]
```

Output example :

```
tail(group1)
  run  size percentage
1:  13 1.149       0.13
2:  14 1.261       0.14
3:  15 1.385       0.14
4:  16 1.520       0.15
5:  17 1.668       0.15
6:  18 1.832       0.16

tail(group2)
   run  size percentage
1:  48 30.07       0.49
2:  49 33.01       0.46
3:  50 36.24       0.45
4:  51 39.78       0.45
5:  52 43.67       0.45
6:  53 47.94       0.44

tail(group3)
   run size percentage
1:  88 1255       0.30
2:  89 1377      0.056
3:  90 1512     0.0044
4:  91 1660          0
5:  92 1822          0
6:     2000
```

Since it seems like you are using `dplyr` or `tidyverse` you could subset the data with :

```
group1 <- data %>% filter(size <= 2)
group2 <- data %>% filter(size > 2 & size <= 50)
group3 <- data %>% filter(size > 50 & size <= 2000)
```

You could also use the `subset()` function from base R.

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you! It works great with my data. One last thing, do you know if there is a way to add all of the `percentage` values together for each group?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want, could you share a example of the expected data you want?

Comment: No worries, I was able to find an answer myself. I was trying to get a cumulative value of the "percentage" response values for each subsetted group. I ended up using `sum(as.numeric(group1$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)` to accomplish this. Thanks for the help though!